# IE Box shadow showing 1px border like effect

Tags: html, css

i have applied box shadow to the mark tag to give extra space on right and left , except IE all other browsers looks fine.But in IE it shows a 1px border like effect . is there any solution for this?

```css
mark {
    font-size: 24px ;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    line-height: 48px;
    max-width:350px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) -15px 0 0 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 15px 0 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) -15px 0 0 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 15px 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) -15px 0 0 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 15px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<mark>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</mark>
```

Comment: its not just like that , my text comes in 2 or 3 lines in a single tag

Comment: The _proper_ solution for that would be padding in combination with `box-decoration-break` (sadly, also not supported yet by IE/Edge.)

Comment: yup , i need a solution for ie

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  mark {
    font-size: 24px ;
    line-height: 48px;
    max-width:350px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(68,68,68); /* Needed for IEs */
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
    zoom: 1;
   }
</style>

<mark>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</mark>
```